# How do I replace the navigation bar on the top with a custom tool bar?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am working on an iPhone application. The application has a navigation bar at the top. I have two views, "root View" and "Child view."

I need to replace navigation bar on the top in "Child View" With (320*20)px View (or custom tool bar) with a custom back button on the top left corner.